# Squeeze Theorem problem with two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am asked to find $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\left(\sin(3x-y)\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)\right)$$
I know the answer is 0, but I have to prove it.
I know that $\cos{\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}}$ is bound between -1 and 1, but I am not quite sure how to set up the full squeeze theorem.

Comment: The Mathjax is not loading on my computer, did I type it in wrong?

Comment: Yes, you did. `\underset` is not defined in mathjax. Just use `\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}` in displaymode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that $\cos{\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}}$ is bound between -1 and 1

This means that
$$
   \left| \sin(3x-y) \cos{\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}} \right| \leq \left|\sin(3x-y)\right|
$$
Furthermore $|\sin(t)| \leq |t|$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. So $|\sin(3x-y)| \leq |3x-y|$.

Does that help?